Changes in Schoenfeld Residuals Dependent on Follow-Up Time
It's my understanding that the proportional hazards assumption means that the effect of a covariate on the hazard rate (or the instantaneous risk of an event) remains constant over time. In practice, this means that the risk of an event for one group should be proportionally higher (or lower) than the other group throughout the entire study period...
I am currently testing two Cox proportional hazards regression models, both of which are identical apart from their follow-up times (5 years and 10 years, respectively). The results of the Schoenfeld test for each model are shown below:
5-Year Model Schoenfeld Test Results:



Variable
Chisq
df
p-value




Depression Level
0.757
2
0.685


Variable 2
5.524
2
0.0632


Variable 3
4.514
2
0.105


Variable 4
11.104
2
0.004


Calendar Year
1.492
1
0.222


Age
7.278
1
0.007


Sex
0.625
1
0.429


Education Level
5.889
1
0.015


Employment Status
22.739
4
<0.001


Marital Status
13.914
3
0.003


Medicaid Status
0.777
1
0.378


Mechanism
26.795
3
<0.001


Variable 13
21.838
1
<0.001


Variable 14
21.566
1
<0.001


Variable 15
12.990
1
<0.001


GLOBAL
31.6802
26
0.001



10-Year Model Schoenfeld Test Results:



Variable
Chisq
df
p-value




Depression Level
6.4271
2
0.040


Variable 2
1.2341
2
0.540


Variable 3
2.0940
2
0.351


Variable 4
0.0656
2
0.968


Calendar Year
1.5297
1
0.216


Age
3.7158
1
0.054


Sex
0.3735
1
0.541


Education Level
0.0380
1
0.845


Employment Status
6.7776
4
0.148


Marital Status
1.8665
3
0.601


Medicaid Status
0.1716
1
0.679


Mechanism
5.0215
3
0.170


Variable 13
0.7751
1
0.379


Variable 14
0.0739
1
0.786


Variable 15
0.2949
1
0.587


GLOBAL
31.6802
26
0.204



Are these results contradictory? That is, is it guaranteed that a covariate that violates the PH assumption in a model with a shorter follow-up time should necessarily violate the PH assumption in a model with a longer follow-up time? In the example above: Is it possible for multiple (9/15) covariates to violate the PH assumption in a Cox regression model that follows participants for 5 years but not for the same model with a 10-year follow-up period?
What could this mean about the set of violating covariates in the 5-year model? Does it mean that the effects of the violating predictors on the hazard of death change more rapidly over the initial 5 years compared to later years? Does it mean, for example, that age and education level have strong initial effects that diminish over time?

Additional Information (as requested by EdM):

This analysis originates from a retrospective cohort study with follow-up interviews collected at 1, 2, 5, and 10 years from the date of injury. The "start time" in the present analysis is the Year 1 interview date. (This was chosen as the start time because the main covariate of interest, depression_level, was not collected until the first follow-up interview.)

The datasets for the 5- and 10-year models contained 1,228 and 1,245 total participants, respectively. There were 113 events in the 5-year model (9.2% mortality rate) and 219 events in the 10-year model (17.6% mortality rate).

We sought to evaluate the 5- and 10-year follow-up periods separately as these are specific time points of interest within the literature on our cohort study (which collects follow-up data at 1, 2, 5, and 10 years after study enrollment) as well as in the field more generally.

The x-axis is measured as time (in years). It's the number of years from the first (Year 1) follow-up interview until either censorship or death.


As requested, here are the Schoenfeld residual plots for a predictor, marital_status, that failed PH in the 5-year model but not the 10-year model:
5-year Schoenfeld residual:

10-year Schoenfeld residual:


Please edit the question to provide more details. How many events were there? What was your purpose in evaluating 5-year and 10-year follow up separately? How comparable were the model fits of the 5-year and 10-year models (ignoring the PH problem)? What did you use as the x-axis time scale in cox.zph()? What do Schoenfeld residual plots look like for a predictor that failed PH in the first model but not in the second?

@EdM I provided the additional context you requested, but I'm unsure what you mean about the comparability of the model fits. Are you asking how similar the resulting HRs were or something else entirely? I haven't run any AIC/BIC tests, as we were primarily basing our decisions on the existing literature.

First, before you worry about violating proportional hazards (PH), worry about overfitting. Having 113 or 219 events might seem like a lot, but your model needs to fit 26 regression coefficients (global df). That's only 4 to 8 events per coefficient. You typically need ~15 events per coefficient to avoid overfitting in typical medical studies. See Chapter 4 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for how to build regression models without overfitting. I suspect that you will have to do some intelligent "data reduction," as he explains, to combine your many predictors into a smaller number based on your understanding of the subject matter.
Second, you seem to be using the survminer package to do your Schoenfeld residual plots. The version you used evidently still has the massive coding error that has led to much confusion among people who visit this site. The confidence bands are so wide, erroneously placed, that the plots end up being almost useless. For these plots I recommend using the functions in the original survival package, as they have been vetted for decades.
Third, the spacing of the values along the time axes of those plots look weird. There is a transform argument to the cox.zph() function that determines not only that spacing along the time axis but also the transformation of time values used for assessing the statistical significance of the PH violation. See this answer for a brief explanation. You typically want the points representing the event times to be reasonably well spaced out horizontally in this display, otherwise the outliers at extreme time values can lead to weird results when you do the corresponding cox.zph() test. I think that's what is affecting you here. The outliers are different in the two models and influence the "significance" of the PH violation differently. The default km transformation of the time axis usually works well, but if that's what you used it didn't work very well on your data. Try a different transformation of time.
Finally, it's quite possible that you have "statistically significant" violations of PH that aren't large enough to matter in practice. See this page for some discussion. Unfortunately, with ggcoxzph() plots you can't really evaluate that. The proper plots will expand the vertical axis so that you can better evaluate how flat the smoothed plots are.
Even if the PH violation is real, you get regression coefficients representing event-averaged values that, if you use robust standard errors, are amenable to inference. See this page for more details and links.

Thank you so much for your thorough response! As you suspected, the default km transformation of the time axis did not function as expected... We're seeing very different results for the Schoenfeld residuals after setting transform to "identity." I appreciate your help!
